# Why is R adding an extra row when converting characters to dates

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, posix

I am converting a vector of character data types to date data types in R using `strptime`.

When I used `sapply` to check the data types after the conversion it gave me back an extra row.

Minimal example below:

```
test_dates = c("2020-10-01","2019-08-09","2018-07-01")
sapply(test_dates,class)
2020-10-01  2019-08-09  2018-07-01 
"character" "character" "character" 

test_dates = strptime(test_dates, "%Y-%m-%d")
sapply(test_dates,class)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "POSIXlt" "POSIXlt" "POSIXlt"
[2,] "POSIXt"  "POSIXt"  "POSIXt"
```

The second row at the end is the bit that I am unsure about. I don't know if it is a misunderstanding of `sapply`, or to do with how R stores times/dates. As below, there is nothing in the second row of the data.

```
test_dates[1][1]
[1] "2020-10-01 BST"
test_dates[1][2]
[1] NA
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R objects can have more than one class. The second row that you are seeing is because `strptime` returns object with two classes i.e `POSIXlt` and `POSIXt`. As you are using `sapply` it simplifies the data into a matrix which might be confusing.

Maybe output of `lapply` would be less confusing.

```
lapply(test_dates, class)

#[[1]]
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

#[[3]]
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Also a vector can have only one class so you can check `class` of the whole vector instead of each individual element since it will return the same value anyway.

```
class(test_dates)
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Thanks @ronak-shah both for the explanation and the extra hint. Do you know why dates have two classes? Is it because one is the "pure" POSIX time, kept in the background, and the other is the version shown to the user, which is the local time?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why there are two classes for date-time variables. Additinoally, I know this is not what your question asked but if you have only date values you can keep them as only date using `as.Date(test_dates)` which will give you "Date" class.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily convert this vector to date using the lubridate package (ymd function). Something like that:

```
test_dates <- c("2020-10-01","2019-08-09","2018-07-01")
new_dates <- lubridate::ymd(test_dates)
class(new_dates)
```

hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there an advantage to using this over strptime?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `map`

```
library(purrr)
map(test_dates, class)
```